# Why is this XML header tag invalid?

Tags: xml

If I enter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

into www.xmlvalidation.com it puts a cross next to xml and says "The processing instruction target matching [xX],mM][lL] is not allowed".

What is it complaining about?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

It is complaining that this material is not the very first thing in the file, so it's trying to be interpreted at a PI instead of a header.

Comment: It was the first line, but after some more experimentation it seems copying/pasting was adding a white space character before the opening < and that causes it to complain.

Comment: Perhaps it's broken? Perhaps it doesn't permit <?xml?> ?